# Error: cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick') /// but works in localhost

Tags: javascript, button, three.js, onclick, mouseevent

Button isn't clicked in mobile and also github server.
It only works in my localhost...

I have `cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')` error on live server and github server(https://yyoonn12.github.io/three-js-webpack/).
However, it works in my localhost. No that error.
Also, hover event(turning color to white) is working...

I think something wrong in button click event code.

This is html code.

```
<body>
    <div id="overlay">
      <button id="startButton" type="button">HAPPY BIRTHDAY</button>
      <audio id="song" src=""></audio>
    </div>

    ...

    <script src="public/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r105/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is js code.

```
if (WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable()) {
        
  //button
  const startButton = document.getElementById( 'startButton' );
  startButton.addEventListener("pointerdown",init);
...

  function init() {
    const overlay = document.getElementById( 'overlay' );

    setTimeout(function () {
      overlay.classList.add('bgFadeOut');
    }, 0);

    setTimeout(function () {
      overlay.remove();
    }, 1000);
  }
...
} else {

}
```

Help me.. Please...

Comment: Please add relevant code with `open-modal-btn`

Comment: There is another error too `Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined` Try adding: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.144.0/three.min.js"></script>`